# Automated Checked the checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I am working for filtering. I need the JavaScript Solution for this-

When I take any value with my input field, the checkbox checked automated.

[image: image example]

```
<div class="form-check  col-md-3 mb-2 px-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_out" class="checkout_box form-check-input ms-0" id="checkout_box">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="checkout_box">Check Out</label>
        <input type="text" name="check_out" class="check_out form-control" autocomplete="off" id="check_out" required="true">
      </div>
            <div class="form-check col-md-2 mb-2 px-1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="booking_type" class="booking_type form-check-input mr-2 ms-0" id="booking_type">
                <label class="form-check-label mr-0 ml-0" for="booking_type">Booking Type</label>
                <select name="booking_type" onchange="booking_typef(value)" class="form-select mr-0 type_id" id="booking_type">
                        <option value="">Booking Type</option>
                        <option value="package">Package</option>
                        <option value="bungalow">Bungalow</option>
                        <option value="room">Room</option>
                </select>
            </div>.
```

Comment: Please describe the issue in some detail as to what you've done so far, and what you need to achieve exactly. Please consider adding a code sample as well for everyone to understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @SarveshChitko sir,
When I get value in Input field, the checkbox checked is automatic.

Answer (score 1):

On drop down change you can checked uncheck value of checkbox. Uncheck checkbox if dropdown value is empty else check checkbox.

```js
$("#booking_type1").on('change', function() {
  var chk = !$(this).val() == "" ? $("#booking_type").prop("checked", true) : $("#booking_type").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check col-md-2 mb-2 px-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="booking_type" class="booking_type form-check-input mr-2 ms-0" id="booking_type">
  <label class="form-check-label mr-0 ml-0" for="booking_type">Booking Type</label>
  <select name="booking_type" class="form-select mr-0 type_id" id="booking_type1">
    <option value="">Booking Type</option>
    <option value="package">Package</option>
    <option value="bungalow">Bungalow</option>
    <option value="room">Room</option>
  </select>
</div>.
```

Note: ID must be unique . I change your duplicate ID on demo example.